# Manually splitting polyline into two parts at specific vertex?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing

I defined a brand new shapefile as a polyline type in ArcCat. When I opened ArcMap (10.1) and started an editing session, I had no problems adding vertices. I would now like to manually add a point at the start of the line - but I am having unexpected difficulty.

Edit: I think I may be taking the wrong approch here:

While in editing mode with the shapefile selected, "point - adds point to the edit sketch" is greyed out. If I go to Editor> Construct Points, I get the error: "The map does not contain a point target. Add an editable point layer and / or a point template to the map."

I am confused at this message. Is the polyline not a point target? Under my Create Features window, the shapefile shows up with the "Line" construction tools. Is the polyline not the "template to map"?)

I have looked at [online help related to my question](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exercise_1a_Creating_new_points/001t00000019000000/) - but in my case, I can't can the point tool they mention in step 9.

EDIT: I think I may have misunderstood the purpose of "add point" - I thought this was how to manually "split" a line into two and have the line acquire a row in its attribute table. So to rephrase my question: how do I define a vertex so that it "splits" a line into two segments? (I'm no longer sure what "add points" is meant for)

Comment: You need a separate feature layer for different geometry types. You need to create a point layer to add your points at the end of the line.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear if I understand you to be saying that I need to make another point (rather than polyline) shapefile? I am trying to add a point to my polyline so that point will come up as a row in that polyline shapefile's attribute table.

Comment: @Mapperz is correct, you cannot have more than 1 type of geometry in a shapefile, feature class, etc. (See technical nuance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Mixing_shape_types).)

Comment: To be clear, I believe @Mapperz means a separate shapefile or feature class, not just feature layer which does not necessarily imply a separate shapefile or feature class.

Comment: separate feature layer for different geometry type = separate shapefiles for point and lines

Comment: Think the word 'point' in this question is meaning 'node' along with vertices.

Comment: Mapperz, indeed, I should be saying vertex rather than point. Would it not be inappropriate to call a vertex that splits a single line a node? From what I understand of recent readings, a node is either at an "end" or it is an intersect (in a topology). It seem that ArcGIS uses the two terms interchangable a lot of the time...perhaps not best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help topic [Methods for splitting line features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000057000000):

> You can easily split line features to break them into several line features. There are several methods to split lines:
>
> - At the location where you click (Editor toolbar > Split tool)
> - At a specific distance or percentage (Editor menu > Split command)
> - Into an equal number of parts (Editor menu > Split command)
> - At intersections, either existing or where lines are extended to meet (Advanced Editing toolbar > Line Intersection tool)
> - At all intersections (Advanced Editing toolbar > Planarize Lines)
> - At specific distances, with any leftover line length being apportioned among the segments (COGO toolbar > Proportion command)
> - At each vertex of the line or at points along a line (Split Line At Vertices or Split Line At Points geoprocessing tools)

It sounds like you want to use the [Split tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m80000000r000000) on the Editor toolbar.